# Where to install my self-signed certificate

Tags: windows, security, certificate, x509certificate

I need to install my self-signed certificate in my clients machine and follwed the steps in [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172241.aspx).

But in the command in this document shows `certmgr.exe -add good.cer -c -s -r localMachine TrustedPublisher`  where as the document in WDK "WinDDK/7600.16385.1/src/general/build/driversigning/selfsign_readme.htm#_Toc138233166" has the same command named as `"trustedpublisher"`.

```
certmgr.exe -add certfilename.cer -s -r localMachine trustedpublisher
```

Which one is correct among this? Where the certificate will be installed? Also,
I can only find folder named `"Trusted Publisher"` in my Pc.

So where should I install the certificate apart from "Root"?

Please guide me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `TrustedPUblisher` in this case is a certificate store, and not a command line parameter, and Microsoft Windows is not case sensitive for this kind of thing, either case should work.

For a self-signed certificate, you should most likely add the certificate to both `Root` and `TrustedPublisher`.

Comment: but I can find only the folder named "Trusted Publisher" in my PC. i.e there is a space between Trusted and Publisher. what should I do in this case.

Comment: @user1317084, don't use "Trusted Publishers". Use the store names from [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204781.aspx). I verified that they are not case sensitive. Also, if this is not working for you, ensure that you're running certmgr.exe as administrator.